# tempo de sessão em php

Tags: php

Colegas.

Existe algum meio de determinar um tempo em que a sessão deverá permanecer ativa? O motivo é que tenho um sistema do qual uso sessões, porém se o usuário permanecer inativo por um determinado período, parece que a sessão fica inativa, fazendo com que o usuário se logue novamente. Existe algum meio de inibir isso? Não gostaria de usar cookies, pois alguns browsers podem estar com essa funcionalidade inativa.

Comment: Eu penso que isso tem haver com os cookies então teria de alterar o tempo nos cookies

Comment: Sim, pelo arquivo de configuração `php.ini`. Mas você quer deixar com quanto tempo ? Pra sempre ?

Comment: vc pode limitar sim vejo a resposta tenho u metodo que uso pra isso msm

Comment: Dá uma lida [nessa discussão](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/1432957) do SOen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No script de login você coloca:

```
$_SESSION["sessiontime"] = time()+360;
#caso queira um tempo mais so fazer as contas em segundos
```

Esse script coloco em um include que toda pagina que o usuario acessar ele chama esse include.

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION["sessiontime"] ) ) 
            { 
                if ($_SESSION["sessiontime"] < time() ) 
                {
                    session_destroy();
                    header ("location:login.php");
                   #se session for menor que o time ele
                   #destroi a session e redireciona pra login
                } 
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION["sessiontime"] = time() + 360;
                   #se session for maior que o o time ele adiciona mais 360
                   #na sessiontime 

                }
            } 
            else
            { 
                header ("location:login.php");
                #se sessiontime tiver vazia ele ja direto pra login.php
            }
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos. A resposta do Thalles Daniel me ajudou.